# Can not resolve symbol Rider C#

Tags: c#, rider

Проект webApi. Создал новый контроллер и хотел подключить пространство имен Web.Http, но пишет "не удается разрешить символ http", в чем проблема?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Web.Http;
using WebApiJack.Models;

namespace WebApiJack.Controllers
{
    public class ProductsController : Controller
    {
        Product[] products = new Product[] 
        { 
            new Product { Id = 1, Name = "Tomato Soup", Category = "Groceries", Price = 1 }, 
            new Product { Id = 2, Name = "Yo-yo", Category = "Toys", Price = 3.75M }, 
            new Product { Id = 3, Name = "Hammer", Category = "Hardware", Price = 16.99M } 
        };

        public IEnumerable<Product> GetAllProducts()
        {
            return products;
        }

        public IHttpActionResult GetProduct(int id)
        {
            var product = products.FirstOrDefault((p) => p.Id == id);
            if (product == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return Ok(product);
        }
    }
}
```

P.S. Уже искал ответы, но нашел только для VS

Comment: Попробуй установить через nuget Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core и после этого должно заработать. [Тут](https://forums.asp.net/t/2096814.aspx?Where+do+I+find+system+web+Http) говорят что поможет

Comment: @Tivyram сейчас попробую... Все, помогло, оформляй ответом)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Установите Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core через Nuget и пространство имен System.Web.Http будет доступно.